# How do I watch an array index in a for loop in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

I have an array of objects
`const myArray = ref([{0: '1'}, {1: '38'}, {2: '86'}, {4: '22'}])`

And I want to add a watcher over every single index (because I want to retrieve that index for later logic) so I'm doing:

```
onMounted(()=>{
    for(let i = 0; i < myArray.value.length; i++){
        watch(myArray.value[i], (newVal)=>{
            console.log(newVal, i)
        })
    }
})
```

But nothing is showing in console. I've also tried using `array.forEach((value,index)=>{//code})` but it also shows nothing in console.

The thing is when I do the watch over the whole array:

```
for(let i = 0; i < myArray.value.length; i++){
        watch(myArray.value, (newVal)=>{
            console.log(newVal, i)
        })
}
```

It displays the whole array 4 times as expected with the proper index.

I've looked everywhere for an answer why `watch()` doesnt work over array indexes but I cant find any, only thing I found is that in Vue2: You can watch each element in an array or dictionary for change independently with `$watch('arr.0', () => {})` or `$watch('dict.keyName', () => {})`. But that doesn't work in Vue3

Edit (solved): solved it myself. Basically I had to use a getter and return it using at(index). I don't know why that is if someone has an explenation let me know.
Code:

```
    for(let i = 0; i < head_blend_data.value.length; i++){
        watch(()=>head_blend_data.value.at(i), (newVal)=>{
            console.log(newVal, i)
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: First, composition of your array object is wrong ```const myArray = ref([{0: '1'}. {1: '38'}. {2: '86'}. {4: '22'}])``` have *dot(.)* separation. It should be *comma(,)*. Make sure your **myArray** data is correct.

Comment: its correct in the code i just wrote it manually, typo mistake. Updated in the post

Comment: @CaptainCrasi Can you please try with `deep: true` in watcher.